# Separate X screen + TwinView on NVIDIA GT 440

Tags: 10.04, xorg, nvidia, screen

I want to use 3 displays connected on one Nvidia GeForce GT 44O under Ubuntu 10.04.
So there is my configuration:

- 1 display 1680x1050_60
- 1 display 1280x1024_60
- 1 DLP 1920x1080_60 (video projector)

I want to have the two display in TwinView mode (extended desktop) and have the projector on a separate X screen in order to launch XBMC at boot on it.
When I try to configure displays as said previously in nvidia-settings, I cannot activate 3 displays at the same time nor use "TwinView" and "Separate X screen" at the same time.
Is it possible to do what I want ? If yes could you give me the xorg configuration?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, although I think you might be asking a little too much of your video card.

Xorg configurations are slightly personal things, in that it's difficult to write one at a distance for someone without having access to their machine or knowing a lot of key details.

The steps involved would be:

- Backing up your working xorg.conf for reference
- Using the nvidia-settings tool to generate an xorg.conf for your twinview'd screens
- Using nvidia-settings again to generate an xorg.conf for your projector
- Combining both files (with a view to your wokring xorg.conf), giving each it's own *server* flag and making sure you don't have conflicting name spaces

If everything goes wrong you can always fall back to the defaults using:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg -phigh
```

If you're struggling post where you're at and I (or someone else, I dare-say) will try and help you- but simply writing one from scratch without access to the machine in question is beyond my abilities!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please find hereafter my two xorg.conf.    http://pastebin.com/Z3vJLK9S (with tweenview) and http://pastebin.com/WfZitaEg (separate x screen). I tried joining both file but if I activate tweenview the projector switch of and if I desactivate it  I've got the projector but the display in 1280x1024 swith off...

Comment: Ok- try this: http://pastebin.com/kMC1GczH (although I'd be surprised if I got it right first time, so BACKUP! and feel free to return with any errors you can't sort.)

Comment: I tested your xorg.conf but it's not working : I have my two displays in tweenview mode and the projector is still disabled. Please don't hesitate to ask me if you need more information on my configuration...